# Вывод данных на TForm

Tags: c++, массивы, c++builder

Сама я техник и в программировании ни черта не разбираюсь, а сделать надо. По этому если у кого будет возможность помогите, пожалуйста!

У меня ни как не получается реализовать интерфейс для ввода элемента двухмерного массива и организовать нахождение суммы введенных элементов и вывод НА TForm! Вот что у меня поучилось с кодом, но я не могу разобраться с выводом на форму… Да какое там, я на столько чайник в программировании, что не уверена что код правильно написан и проверить не знаю как… Тупо по учебнику подбирала, да еще чел один рядом сидел подсказывал, а еще и крин-шот нужен:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
int m, n;
std::cout << «Введите размер матрицы: »;
std::cin >> m >> n;
int mat[m][n], sum = 0;
std::cout << «Введите элементы матрицы: » << std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
std::cin >> mat[j];
}
}
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
for(int j = 0 ; j < n; j++)
{
sum += mat[j];
}
}
std::cout << «Сумма всех элементов равна » << sum << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Тут даже не главное сам код, главное создание  TForm, а для этого надо хотя бы ИМЕТЬ среду разработки, коей у меня нема, и скачать ни как.(ну и знание КАК это все делатся).
Пробовала сама что то накрутить, но не получается как бы мне обьясняли!!!

Comment: @рина, в следующий раз, чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: используйте компонент TStringGrid

Comment: `TForm`? А какой это фреймворк? Что-то Борландовское?

Comment: @VladD Borland C++ builder скорее всего, те же компоненты что и у Delphi, но на C++